# How are the orbitals named?

Tags: atomic-physics, terminology, orbitals, pauli-exclusion-principle, term-symbols

l = 0 to (n-1).
l is azimuthal quantum number.
n is principal quantum number.

for,

l = 0 , it is s.
l = 1 , it is p.
…
l = 99, it is what?

What is the name given to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first four states are s,p,d,f.  If these letters ever had any obvious meaning, they don’t any more.  (I vaguely recall that two of them were associated with “sharp” and “diffuse” spectral lines.)

For $\ell\ge 4$, the letters just continue alphabetically: $\ell=4,5,6,7$ correspond to g-, h-, i-, and j-orbitals.

You ask about $\ell=99$: nobody goes that high. It’s not even a problem to ask about the possible duplicate label following the r-orbitals with $\ell=12$, because no one goes that high, either.

Comment: Seems there's also an "x-ray notation" as well: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-ray_notation

Comment: X-rays are mostly labeled by the *principal* quantum number, which is a better proxy for the x-ray energy. So the innermost orbital electrons are the K-shell, then the L-shell, etc. The s-wave, p-wave, etc. labels refer to the *angular momentum* quantum number.

Comment: at some point it's just called a Rydberg atom...but that's an excited state.

Answer (score 3):

The azimuthal quantum numbers $\ell=0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,...$
are historically designated by the letters $s,p,d,f,g,h,i,k,...$

[image]
<sub>(table from [Azimuthal quantum number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Azimuthal_quantum_number))</sub>

But in practice only the first four ($s,p,d,f$) are needed because
higher numbers usually don't occur in atomic orbitals.

Comment: Oh, I forgot that we also skip $j$. I blame the fact that nobody goes that high.